# git show command not giving the correct output when using a docker image

Tags: bash, git, docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I wrote a bash script to run a branch cleanup for a repository, which will consider the branches which are not used in 3 months and send an email to the branch owner. In the script I wrote there is a small function which gets the branch name and the last committed date using git commands. Tis is how it looks like,

```
get_active_branches(){
    declare -ag active_branches=()

    echo -e "\e[1;32m Scanning all active branches... \e[0m"

    for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`; do 
        branch_data=$(git show --format=%cs "$branch" | head -n 1)
        active_branches+=("$branch_data $branch")
    done 

    echo -e "\e[1;32m Done. \e[0m"
}
```

I am running this in a docker image, created using osixia/openldap as the base image. I'm using that image because I need to have access to an active directory in a ldap server to get the email address by providing the username of a developer.

The issue is that when I run the above function in a bitbucket pipeline, for the command `branch_data=$(git show --format=%cs "$branch" | head -n 1)` the `branch_data` variable get the value as `%cs`, for an example,

```
git show --format=%cs master
 branch_data=%cs
```

The Dockerfile I'm using is lokks like this,

```
FROM osixia/openldap

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tar xz-utils git openssl bash curl jq gcc libc-dev vim coreutils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install kubectl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y util-linux bash fortune sed findutils openssh-client git jq openssl curl && \
    curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.21.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl > /usr/bin/kubectl && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/kubectl 

# Add actual scripts to /bin
ADD bb_cleanup_new.sh /bin/
```

bb_cleanup_new.sh is the script file which has the function.

Any suggestions to fix this issue.

I tested the script locally and everything works fine.
I thought maybe it's the issue with the branch name having the prefix of `origin/`, so I tested after removing the prefix and running a bitbucket pipeline but it still gives the same result.
It only gives the issue when I'm using the image.

Comment: what version of git is installed in the docker image?

Comment: It's git version 2.20.1

Comment: Is the script run by `bash` in the docker? Does it help if `--format="%cs"` is used? I think `git log -1` would be more memory-efficient than `git show` + `head -n 1`.

Comment: yes it is run by bash, I checked your idea but still the same

Comment: Can you get other information from the branch successfully? What happens if you do `git cat-file -p $branch`?

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of your bitbucket-pipelines.yml on how this is script is used? Is this script run in any pull-request pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

git requires access to the .git directory of your repository. Otherwise it won't be able to show you any information specific to your repository.

You can mount the git repo during the runtime of your container.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#volume

```
docker run -v /path/to/your_git_repo:/path_in_container image
```

If you add the git repository to your Dockerimage, than it would also be possible to access the data from it.

```
ADD your_repo /git_repo/
RUN /git_repo/bin/bb_cleanup_new.sh
```

Also be aware, that your docker context would also require all credentials that are to be used to access remote repositories.
(~/.ssh, global git config, git credential cache etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much for you input, Actually when I'm running the pipeline I clone my desired repository and I run the scripts inside that directory. I have a separate function to clone the repository. so when I run the for loop that's mentioned above it gets me the branch name but the git show command is the one that's not working

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was, it was `%cs` it doesn't give me a value when I'm running in the pipeline, and when I use something else like `%ci, %cr, %ae` it gives me the respective value, so I used `%ci` and did some string manipulation with AWK to get the date. Everything works fine now.

Comment: `%cs` works just fine for me. What docker image are you using to run the script in the pipelines?